# Continue SSIS Package After Error

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, ssis, oledb, business-intelligence

What I did so far:
1.Set Propagate to False
2.set MaximumErrorCount to high value on ForeachContainer 
3. set FailPAckageONFailure to true on each task in workflow 
4. set ForceExecutionResult to Success on DataFlow
5. set ForceExecutionResult to Success on Package

Yes, the execution is successful

[image]

But Inside the Data Flow Task,
[image]
the execution stopped reading xml in xml task, because an error occurs about output column in occupancy 
"[XML Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElLrh.png)] Error: The "component "XML Source" (1)" failed because error code 0x80131537 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "isNotHabitable" (138)" at "output "occupancy" (130)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component." 
***What I want is to continue inserting to access table from  xml even there is an error in occupancy because Ill create an exception handler in Event Handler to insert this error to another table.***

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to double click on XML source component, Select error output and then Redirect row in the dropdown menu "Set this value to selected cells:". This will create an error output on your component, i.e. a red arrow, that you can redirect to the destination of your choice.

Comment: If I do this, The exception will not be thrown right? because I redirect the row to another table which resolve the exception. I also kinda need the error produced.

Comment: I see, sorry, I misunderstood the problem. What you can do is insert the error rows directly to the destination table and bypass the error handler. Alternatively you can force the call to the error handler with a script component but this would be a bit messy.